# Iteratate Through a Dictionary in a POST request

Tags: python, curl, post, request

Hi i try to iterate a dictionary but doesnt work, i already try diferents ways but not figure it out
this is the code:

```
import requests

items_id = ['MLM594466110']

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

params = (
    ('access_token', 'MY_ACCESS_TOKEN'),
)

for i in items_id:

    data = '{"text":"Text","item_id":"{i}"}'

    response = requests.post('https://api.webpage.com/questions/{i}', headers=headers, params=params, data=data)
    print(response)
```

Comment: Do you run this with an access token?

Comment: `response` is an object. So, to parse it as a dictionary (`json`) object, then you need to use `dictionary = response.json()`

Comment: If put the value of the item_id in data, it works, because the { i } that i already put in the response its ok the problem is in the dictionary, i already try data = '{"text":"Text","item_id":"{}".format()}'   but doesnt work

Comment: Have you tried to use `format` with both of them. By both, I mean the `data` object and the `requests.post()` method?

Comment: response = requests.post('https://api.webpage.com/questions/{}'.format(i) in the response works but i dont know how to make the format in the dictionary    data = '{"text":"Text","item_id":"{}"}'.format(i) like this?

Comment: Not exactly... i've added an answer. Hopefully, this is what you were looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formating your `data` object will be a little bit difference since it uses nested string values. So, the simplest solution is to use `%` notation like so:

```
for i in items_id:
    data = '{"text":"Text","item_id":"{%s}"}'  %str(i) #<--- notice using %s here which stands for string

    response = requests.post(f'https://api.webpage.com/questions/{i}', headers=headers, params=params, data=data) #<--- notice adding `f` just after post(
```

Comment: ValueError: Invalid format specifier still have this problem, thanks

Comment: I didn't notice it's a nested string.. I've edited my answer now

Comment: TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str              this is the last error

Comment: Well first was a <Response [500]> and then a <Response [404]> but i think was everything ok, its the api that doesnt work